# KDE Plasma 5.8.3 Lock Screen - How to enable on screen keyboard by default?

Tags: linux, kde, user-interface, wireless-keyboard

How can I enable the on screen keyboard by default on the Lock Screen in KDE Plasma 5.8.3?

Comment: The lock screen is handled by your display manager, eg. SDDM, LightDM or GDM. On Debian based systems, you can typically find out which display manager you're using by running the command `cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager`, but other distros handle such things differently.

Comment: @flesk I'm not sure that is really true for the KDE lock screen. Plasma 5 uses SDDM, but uses a new screen locker which is given a high level, early overview [here](https://blog.martin-graesslin.com/blog/2014/05/screenlocker-architecture-in-plasma-next/) - it's not integrated with the display manager, and is essentially new from the ground up.

The on-screen keyboard, similarly, is a brand new item that is detailed [on the same blog](https://blog.martin-graesslin.com/blog/2016/05/virtual-keyboard-support-in-kwinwayland-5-7/).